SyntaxError: Identifier 'client' has already been declared ( Bitte um Hilfe )
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:128:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1332:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

sd

von neu geschrieben immer wieder der gleiche fehler

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
